# run linux application on html file

Tags: linux, html

I tried to run **geany** on html button but it didn't work.

Can any one help me Please

`<a class="btn btn-block btn-info" href="cmd://geany"> Run Geany </a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run arbitrary commands from a webpage as that would be a security risk.
You could however register a new protocol (eg. geany://) that would open your favorite editor.

The procedure is documented [here](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http-) for linux and Windows.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu, you would have to create a .desktop file that looks like this:

```
sudo tee /usr/share/applications/geany-handler.desktop > /dev/null <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Geany URL Handler
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Handle URL Scheme geany://
Exec=geany
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/geany;
Icon=
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Geany URL Handler
EOF
```

Comment: thank's for your help but can you give me a example